# JS replace todos os caracteres iguais

Tags: javascript, replace

Estou tentando usar a função replace para transformar uma letra em 0, porém isso não funciona quando eu quero testar a letra dentro de uma var.

```
var palavra = "abelha";
var letra = 'A';
palavra = palavra.replace(/(letra)/g, '0');
```

Alguma solução?

Comment: Tenta esse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/6647038

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar `new RegExp(padrão, flags)`, mas é preciso usar a flag `i` também para ignorar *case sensitive* (não diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas):

```js
var palavra = "abelha";
var letra = 'A';
var re = new RegExp(letra, 'gi');
palavra = palavra.replace(re, '0');

console.log(palavra);
```

Comment: funcionou aqui, valeu!!! aproveitando aqui, como faço pra verificar se na string tudo é zero? no caso a palavra inteira fica 0 aqui, porém eu tentei com if(!NaN(palavra)) e ainda não mostra

Comment: @PauloHenriqueRodriguesGrund Nessa caso, é fazer outra pergunta

Comment: vc quer ver se é palavra = "0000000" ?

Comment: vou fazer uma outra pergunta entao, mas vou ter que esperar um pouco pra fazer

Comment: Eu já respondi uma pergunta parecida, mas não tô achando rs

Comment: Mas o certo é `isNaN`...

Comment: eu tento com isNaN mas nao funciona, mesmo que esteja tudo 0

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307757/verificar-se-uma-string-%C3%A9-apenas-composta-de-0