# Verificar se uma string é apenas composta de 0

Tags: javascript

Eu quero verificar se por exemplo uma string "00000000" é composta apenas de zeros e dê true, porém uma "0000a0e0b" seja false, porquê eu tentei com !isNaN e dá true tendo pelo menos 1 número

```
var palavra = 00000;
var palavra2 = a00a0;
if(!isNaN(palavra)) // Aqui é pra dar true
if(!isNaN(palavra2)) // Aqui era pra dar false, mas dá true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você está testando strings, uma alternativa é usar expressões regulares:

```js
var palavra = "00000";
var palavra2 = "a00a0";

console.log(/^0+$/.test(palavra)); // true
console.log(/^0+$/.test(palavra2)); // false
```

- `^` indica o início da string
- `0+` indica uma ou mais ocorrências do `0`
- `$` indica o final da string

Ou seja, a expressão `/^0+$/` corresponde a uma string com uma ou mais ocorrências de `0`, do início ao fim.

O método `test` verifica se a string passada corresponde à expressão.

Comment: Removi a minha. ;)

Comment: Tem problema não, a sua resposta ficou ótima.

Comment: @dvd Eu tinha pensado em remover a minha também. Nunca tinha acontecido isso antes e fiquei em dúvida sobre o que fazer.. De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Comment: Nestes casos quem respondeu por último que deveria remover a resposta. Mas como foi praticamente ao mesmo tempo, tomei a iniciativa. Não tem problema não. Ainda bem que vc avisou porque eu nem tinha visto a sua resposta rs.

Comment: muito obrigado a todos que responderam, funcionou aqui :)

Answer (score 4):

> Como a minha resposta anterior ficou idêntica ao do @hkotsubo e postamos  exatamente ao mesmo tempo, vou deixar uma variante para referência.

Pode usar também uma expressão regular de negação:

```
[^0]
```

O sinal `^` (*negated set* ou "conjunto negado") irá verificar se na string tem qualquer outro caractere que não seja `0`. Se encontrar é porque não tem apenas `0`. Para inverter a verificação, você pode usar o sinal `!`. No caso, `true` irá indicar que só tem `0`.

Exemplo:

```js
var palavra = "00000000";
var palavra2 = "0000a0e0b";

console.log(!/[^0]/.test(palavra)); // retorna true, só contém 0
console.log(!/[^0]/.test(palavra2)); // retorna false, não tem só 0 ou nem tem 0
```

Comment: Muito bom, não tinha pensado nessa alternativa. Como eu já tinha votado antes, mantenho meu voto! ;)

Comment: gostei dessa alternativa, vou tentar usar ela numa proxima c;

Comment: @PauloHenriqueRodriguesGrund Legal. Eu só coloquei para mostrar que se pode fazer de formas diferentes.

Answer (score 4):

Eu forçaria uma conversão para número com o [operador `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), depois checaria se deu `0`. É bem simples:

```js
var palavra = '00000';
var palavra2 = 'a00a0';
console.log(+palavra === 0);
console.log(+palavra2 === 0);
```

Apenas um porém: se a string for `0b00000` (com qualquer quantidade de zeros após o `b`), poderá ser interpretada como string binária de valor `0` ([suporte depende](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-octal_and_binary_literals) do browser), e o resultado da comparação dará `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Como já tem respostas com expressões regulares, mostro-lhe uma alternativa sem expressões regulares, apesar de não ser tão compacto.

A ideia é testar com outra string construída com zeros, para a mesma quantidade de letras, à custa do método [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) de string. Este `repeat` irá repetir um zero várias vezes até ter o tamanho correspondente.

Exemplo:

```js
var palavra = "00000000";
var palavra2 = "0000a0e0b";

console.log(palavra === "0".repeat(palavra.length));
console.log(palavra2 === "0".repeat(palavra2.length));
```

Comment: boa solucao, porem no caso sao varias palavras, nao tem tamanho definido :c